# Any book talks about Apple Darwin internal?

Tags: darwin

Windows and Linux have numerous books talking about their internal architectures. I would like to know if there is such a book talking the same topic about Apple Darwin/XNU. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little old (2007), but [Mac OS X Internals: A Systems Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321278542), by Amit Singh, is a lengthy guide to OSX history, the XNU kernel, and filesystems. It notably leaves out networking.